# I am Working on Ble Android Application. while receiving data from esp32 server my app got crash showing Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=172

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

here i paste my logs data please help me , i am newbie to Android ble

```
488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
2023-09-29 15:40:39.867 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
2023-09-29 15:40:39.890 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
2023-09-29 15:40:39.890 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
2023-09-29 15:40:39.900 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
2023-09-29 15:40:39.900 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
2023-09-29 15:40:39.914 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
2023-09-29 15:40:39.914 19329-19358 IMGMapper               com.eapro.myproject                  E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
2023-09-29 15:40:39.929 19329-19329 ViewRootIm...[Connects] com.eapro.myproject                  I  MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 0
2023-09-29 15:40:39.976 19329-19329 DecorView               com.eapro.myproject                  I  [INFO] isPopOver=false config=true
2023-09-29 15:40:39.976 19329-19329 DecorView               com.eapro.myproject                  I  updateCaptionType: isFloating=false isApplication=true hasWindowDecorCaption=false this=DecorView@5b3e97b[]
2023-09-29 15:40:39.976 19329-19329 DecorView               com.eapro.myproject                  D  setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@5b3e97b[]
2023-09-29 15:40:39.981 19329-19329 DecorView               com.eapro.myproject                  I  getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=300 msg=resources_loaded
2023-09-29 15:40:39.982 19329-19329 DecorView               com.eapro.myproject                  I  setWindowBackground: isPopOver=false color=ffffffff d=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@af0d7f1
2023-09-29 15:40:40.144 19329-19339 InputTransport          com.eapro.myproject                  D  Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=172
2023-09-29 15:40:40.144 19329-19339 InputTransport          com.eapro.myproject                  D  Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=119
2023-09-29 15:40:40.187 19329-19337 eapro.myproject         com.eapro.myproject                  I  Compiler allocated 4177KB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2023-09-29 15:40:40.196 19329-19329 <no-tag>                com.eapro.myproject                  D  javedesp32
2023-09-29 15:40:40.199 19329-19329 <no-tag>                com.eapro.myproject                  D  oldhaiesp32
2023-09-29 15:40:41.225 19329-19329 DetailBlewrite fail     com.eapro.myproject                  D  BleException { code=102, description='gatt writeCharacteristic fail'}
2023-09-29 15:40:41.225 19329-19329 Tag                     com.eapro.myproject                  D  msg0
2023-09-29 15:40:41.230 19329-19329 DetailBlewrite fail     com.eapro.myproject                  D  BleException { code=102, description='gatt writeCharacteristic fail'}
2023-09-29 15:40:41.230 19329-19329 Tag                     com.eapro.myproject                  D  msg0
2023-09-29 15:40:41.736 19329-19329 BluetoothGatt           com.eapro.myproject                  D  setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8 enable: true
2023-09-29 15:40:42.748 19329-19329 BluetoothGatt           com.eapro.myproject                  D  configureMTU() - device: D4D4DA_2 mtu: 200
2023-09-29 15:40:42.750 19329-19329 DetailBleonCreate       com.eapro.myproject                  D  Device id not connected
2023-09-29 15:40:42.754 19329-19329 DetailBle               com.eapro.myproject                  D  Connected
```

I want to show data on my ui from esp32 server.in android Application
i am working on ble Android Application and other person on esp32 module

Comment: Your question does not contain helpful information about the problem. Please visit [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Kozmotronik Use code formatting for computer output. You can see for yourself that it's much more readable.

Comment: Yes @user207421, you are right. I will consider it from now on, thank you.